# To prove inequality involving integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose $f$ is a function (sufficiently smooth on $\mathbb{R}$). Then show that there exists $C>0$ such that for any interval $I=[a,b]$ of length $h$ we have
>
> $$ \left(\int\limits_{I} g(x)^2\ dx \right)^{1/2}  \leq C \left\{ \left( |g(a)|+|g(b)| 
>  \right)h^{1/2} + \left(\int\limits_{I} g''(x)^2\ dx \right)^{1/2}h^2 \right\}$$

I was reading through a research paper and they assume this fact. I don't know how one would prove this.

Comment: That makes me think of Euler-MacLaurin formula. Not sure if it will lead you somewhere though.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, $g(x)=g(a)+g'(c)(x-a)$ and $g(b)=g(x)+g'(d)(b-x)$, where $a<c<x$ and $x<d<b$. Also, $$g'(c)=g'(d)+\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt
.$$ Hence,
$$g(x)=g(a)+g'(c)(x-a)=g(a)+(x-a)\left(g'(d)+\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt\right)\\=g(a)+(x-a)\left(\frac{g(b)-g(x)}{b-x}+\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt\right).$$
Then $$g(x)\left(1+\frac{x-a}{b-x}\right)=g(a)+g(b)\frac{x-a}{b-x}+(x-a)\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt.$$
Hence,
$$g(x)\frac{b-a}{b-x}=g(a)+g(b)\frac{x-a}{b-x}+(x-a)\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt,$$
that is,
$$g(x)=g(a)\frac{b-x}{b-a}+g(b)\frac{b-x}{b-a}\frac{x-a}{b-x}+(x-a)\frac{b-x}{b-a}\int_c^dg^{\prime\prime}(t)\,dt.$$
It follows by Holder inequality
$$|g(x)|\le |g(a)|+|g(b)|+h\int_a^b|g^{\prime\prime}(t)|\,dt
\\\le |g(a)|+|g(b)|+h^{3/2}\left(\int_a^b|g^{\prime\prime}(t)|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}$$
Squaring gives
$$|g(x)|^2\le  c|g(a)|^2+c|g(b)|^2+ch^3\int_a^b|g^{\prime\prime}(t)|^2\,dt.$$
Now integrate in $x$.